# Configuring security for a WCF replacement of an old WSE 3.0 service

Tags: web-services, wcf, ssl

I've been tasked with updating an older WSE 3.0 amsx service with a newer WCF service, and it looks like I've got the signature/wsdl of the old service spoofed well enough but I can't seem to get the security configurations set in right.

I'm certainly no WSE wizard but I did find this wse3 policy file entry pertaining to the "Inquiry" service I'm updating:

```
  <extensions>
    <extension name="usernameOverTransportSecurity"
               type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design.UsernameOverTransportAssertion, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <extension name="requireActionHeader"
               type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design.RequireActionHeaderAssertion, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <extension name="mutualCertificate11Security" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design.MutualCertificate11Assertion, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <extension name="x509" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design.X509TokenProvider, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </extensions>

  <policy name="Inquiry">
    <usernameOverTransportSecurity />
    <!--requireActionHeader /-->
  </policy>
...
```

Based off of [this msdn resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732008(v=vs.110).aspx) I should be able to use a custom binding to mimic the wse security, and here's my current web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="portName" type="CustomWsdlExtension.PortNameWsdlBehaviorExtension, TT_Demo3"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="customPortName12">
          <portName name="InquirySoap12"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="OnePointTwo">
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004" />
          <httpsTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="TT_Demo3.Inquiry">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="customBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="OnePointTwo"  
                  contract="InquirySoap" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="customPortName12" 
                  name="InquirySoap12"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The error I'm getting is ***Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding CustomBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].***

I've seen a lot of fixes for this type of issue to be adding a `<security mode="transport" />` element to the binding but CustomBinding doesn't seem to support this.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.